# Connecting Android app to GPS device

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I'm building an android app which will have Google map embedded.

This app should display in the map a number of buses in an area.

I understand I need to install GPS devices on the buses and then connect each device to my app.

My question is; How do I *connect* the **android app** to a **GPS device**?

Really need info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't, directly.  You'd have the GPS device report over the internet to a central server via a webservice.  Then you'd have a second web service provide that data to Android devices which request it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your Android device would contain a GPS chip that can be easily accessed as [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) - just several classes to use and a manifest entry to allow the location access.

I am not aware if any external (USB OTG, I assume) devices are actually supported. If some are, would be cool to know.

Comment: I am unable to visualise external (USB OTG) devices which can help here as the gps devices are not implicitly connected at all to the device where the app runs

Answer (score 0):

You must have a mechanism by which  gps unit in each bus sends out its position periodically to your device where your bus track app is present.

There is a Net-Initiated case in A-GPS(assisted GPS) wherin your app can send the location request to the individual units and on reception of their location, your app can display it. Your GPS units must inevitably networked for this. It is somewhat similar to the use-case wherein, in many social networks, a friend's location is requested by your device and retrieved.